# How do you verify that $(1,2)$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$? (Abstract Algebra Question)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups

I know that for $(1,2)$, in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, $1$ is of order $2$, and in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, $2$ is of order $5$. Since the lcm$(2,5)=10$, is it correct to state that the element $(1,2)$ has order $10$? I don't know how to show that this is the first multiple where $(1,2)=(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times\mathbb{Z}_5$ (which I know has 10 elements). So is showing the order of the element as equal to the number of elements in the entire group a verification that $(1,2)$ is a generator? If not, what would strengthen this?

Comment: \times to get $\times$. Don't use x

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oops, thank you. A bit sleep deprived and forgot the code for it lol!

Answer (score 5):

Just do the sums:
\begin{align*}
(1,2)+(1,2) & = (0,4), \\
(0,4)+(1,2) & = (1,1), \\
(1,1)+(1,2) & = (0,3), \\
(0,3)+(1,2) & = (1,0), \\
(1,0)+(1,2) & = (0,2), \\
(0,2)+(1,2) & = (1,4), \\
(1,4)+(1,2) & = (0,1), \\
(0,1)+(1,2) & = (1,3), \\
(1,3)+(1,2) & = (0,0), \\
(0,0)+(1,2) & = (1,2).
\end{align*}
Look carefully at all the elements you got: they are all elements of $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_5$.

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot to see it all written out like that. If it were a larger group, how would you go about it then?

Comment: The trick is that $2$ and $5$ are coprime, so $2$ is a generator in $\mathbb Z_5$. In fact, all non-trivial elements in $\mathbb Z_5$ are generators, as $5$ is prime. If you had $\mathbb Z_{57}$, all elements that are coprime with $57$ would generate it. For $\mathbb Z_2$ the question is trivial. So in your case it is clear that $(1,2)$ generates the whole group, but $(1,3), (1,4)$ generate it as well.

Comment: I see. I was trying to piece together how being coprime correlates to this, so I appreciate you pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

My preference is to notice that in $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_5$

$$ 5 \cdot (1,2) =(1,0)$$

and

$$ 8 \cdot (1,2)=(0,1)$$

so the subgroup generated by $(1,2)$ contains those two elements, which clearly generate the whole group.

If I wanted to be super explicit, I would use the notation $\langle A\rangle$ to denote the subgroup generated by $A$, for any $A$ that is a subset of a group $G$, and the fact that if $B \subset A$ then $\langle B \rangle \subset \langle A\rangle$. (I haven't written it all out as a detailed answer, I've just kind of given you all the tools necessary. Is it clear enough now, or do you think you need more explanation? You can always take the answers/suggestions you get and write them up yourself as an answer, and ask for people to critique it.)

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to find the multiples you found, 5 and 8, through some sort of process, or did you just do that in your head? I can understand how (1,2) generates all of the elements, but, say we were working with a group with many more elements, then what would we do?

Comment: Well, for this one I just did it in my head. But knowing (for the first one) that I wanted to get 0 in the second slot, I knew I should check 5, 10, 15, 20... Similarly, for the second equality, I knew to check 2, 4, 6, 8, 10.... It doesn't scale for when you have a massive number of elements, but I think the idea of just showing that you can generate a simple known set of generators is with taking away from this example.

Comment: One thing I didn't bother to do here (because this is a pretty simple example) was the following: I could have found the "8" first, and then, knowing $(0,1)$ was in my generated subgroup, I'd also know that $(1,2)-(0,1)-(0,1)=(1,0)$ was in my generated subgroup, and I'd be done. "Generate generators, and use them to generate other generators!"

Comment: In the general case, with larger numbers, we could consider finding those $5$ and $8$ using a system of diophantine equations: for instance, $x \cdot (1, 2) = (1, 0)$ implies $x \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$ and $2x \equiv 0 \pmod{5}.$ Multiplying both sides of the second equation by $3$ (modular inverse of $2$ mod $5$) yields $x \equiv 0 \pmod{5}.$ Then one way to find a solution is to sieve through the numbers from $1$ to $10,$ leveraging the Chinese Remainder Theorem. (I’m sure there are other ways to do it, and probably more efficient ways, but this is at least one way to avoid simply guessing)

Comment: Bezout's Identity is probably the way to go for really huge numbers. The section on it in the Wikipedia article on Euclidean Algorithm is probably a fine place to start.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Right, that makes sense considering it was a small example. "Generate generators and use them to generate other generators" is very helpful so thank you for including that! I appreciate you explaining an alternative method.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful! I phrased it a bit silly-ly, but it can be helpful to understand the more general strategy that's motivating a particular solution. And you should def. try to understand freakish's answer - I certainly had Bezout's thm. and the Euclidean algorithm in mind for this answer.

Comment: I'm glad that I'm very familiar with Bezout's Identity and Euclid's Algorithm, which helps quite a bit. I'm slowly building up my mathematical understanding of Number Theory, which I'm taking along with Abstract Algebra, and so I'm trying my best to build as many connections as I can so I can look at a problem and go, "Oh! I know exactly how I can look at this!" I'm new to this caliber of mathematics but I'm eager to really understand what's going on and why. Slowly but surely I hope to get there.

Answer (score 3):

We can do this more generally:

> **Lemma.** Let $G$, $H$ be groups and $A\subseteq G$, $B\subseteq H$ generating sets, each containing elements of finite order only. Assume that $gcd(|x|,|y|)=1$ for any $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. Then $A\times B$ generates $G\times H$.

*Proof.* Of course $C=A\times\{e_H\}\cup\{e_G\}\times B$ generates $G\times H$, so it is enough to generate $C$ from $A\times B$. In particular it is enough to show that given $(x,y)\in A\times B$ we can generate $(x,e_H)$ and $(e_G,y)$ out of it. We will only focus on $(x,e_H)$ since the other case is symmetric.

As a first step we consider $(x,y)^{|y|}=(x^{|y|},e_H)$. Since $gcd(|x|,|y|)=1$, then by the Bézout's identity there are $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$\alpha\cdot |x|+\beta\cdot |y|=1$$

Therefore

$$x=x^{1}=x^{\alpha\cdot |x|+\beta\cdot |y|}=x^{\beta\cdot |y|}=(x^{|y|})^\beta$$

and so we can generate $x$ from $x^{|y|}$. Meaning we can generate $(x,e_H)$ from $(x^{|y|},e_H)$ and thus from $(x,y)$. This completes the proof. $\Box$

> **Corollary.** $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_5$ is generated by $(1,2)$ element.

which I leave as a simple application of the Lemma above.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write out this proof. The generalization helps me to understand the concept as a whole. I think I'll find some other examples where I can apply this and go about them using your proof to really try and solidify these ideas.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

In a direct product,  the order of any element $(x,y)$ is the $\rm lcm(\lvert x\rvert, \lvert y\rvert).$